# How can I force HtmlUnit to parse a Javascript file in UTF-8 in a GWT Test Case?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, encoding, htmlunit

I'm writing a GWTTestCase on a GWT Module including an external Javascript file which contains non-ASCII characters in variables names (d3.js).

I get this Error :

```
SEVERE: error: message=[illegal character] sourceName=[http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js] line=[2098] lineSource=[    var Î»00, Ï00, Î»0, cosÏ0, sinÏ0;] lineOffset=[10]
```

here is the line of code at line 2098 :

```
var λ00, φ00, λ0, cosφ0, sinφ0;
```

According to HtmlUnit, these characters (λ and φ) are valid Javascript identifier characters (see [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js/2.9/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/corejs/javascript/TokenStream.java?av=f#360)) and browsers have no problem parsing it. Unfortunately, HtmlUnit seems to read the file using ISO-8859-1 encoding (as you can see in the error message), while it is UTF-8 encoded.

How can I force HtmlUnit to use UTF-8 encoding to parse the Javascript file ?

I tried to add the option -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 in Eclipse and in Maven configuration, but it didn't help.
Is there a way to configure HtmlUnit by overriding some method in GWTTestCase ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround to configure HtmlUnit by extending `RunStyleHtmlUnit` and overriding some methods and internal classes.

It's really hugly, but it works...

```
package com.google.gwt.junit;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.w3c.css.sac.CSSParseException;
import org.w3c.css.sac.ErrorHandler;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptErrorListener;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger;

public class RunStyleUtf8HtmlUnit extends RunStyleHtmlUnit {

  private boolean developmentMode;

  public RunStyleUtf8HtmlUnit(JUnitShell shell) {
    super(shell);
  }

  protected static class Utf8HtmlUnitThread extends HtmlUnitThread {
    private final BrowserVersion browser;
    private final TreeLogger treeLogger;
    private final String url;

    public Utf8HtmlUnitThread(BrowserVersion browser, String url,
        TreeLogger treeLogger, boolean developmentMode) {
      super(browser, url, treeLogger, developmentMode);

      this.browser = browser;
      this.treeLogger = treeLogger;
      this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      WebClient webClient = new WebClient(browser);
      webClient.setAlertHandler(this);
      // Adding a handler that ignores errors to work-around
      // https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3090806&group_id=47038&atid=448266
      webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

        public void error(CSSParseException exception) {
          // ignore
        }

        public void fatalError(CSSParseException exception) {
          treeLogger.log(TreeLogger.WARN,
              "CSS fatal error: " + exception.getURI() + " ["
                  + exception.getLineNumber() + ":"
                  + exception.getColumnNumber() + "] "
                  + exception.getMessage());
        }

        public void warning(CSSParseException exception) {
          // ignore
        }
      });
      webClient.setIncorrectnessListener(this);
      webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
      webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
      webClient.setOnbeforeunloadHandler(this);
      webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new JavaScriptErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void loadScriptError(HtmlPage htmlPage, URL scriptUrl,
            Exception exception) {
          treeLogger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "Load Script Error: "
              + exception, exception);
        }

        @Override
        public void malformedScriptURL(HtmlPage htmlPage, String url,
            MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
          treeLogger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "Malformed Script URL: "
              + malformedURLException.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void scriptException(HtmlPage htmlPage,
            ScriptException scriptException) {
          treeLogger.log(TreeLogger.DEBUG, "Script Exception: "
              + scriptException.getLocalizedMessage() + ", line "
              + scriptException.getFailingLine());
        }

        @Override
        public void timeoutError(HtmlPage htmlPage, long allowedTime,
            long executionTime) {
          treeLogger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "Script Timeout Error "
              + executionTime + " > " + allowedTime);
        }
      });
      setupWebClient(webClient);
      try {
        WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(new URL(url));
        webRequest.setCharset("utf-8");
        Page page = webClient.getPage(webRequest);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(2000);
        if (treeLogger.isLoggable(TreeLogger.SPAM)) {
          treeLogger.log(TreeLogger.SPAM, "getPage returned "
              + ((HtmlPage) page).asXml());
        }
        // TODO(amitmanjhi): call webClient.closeAllWindows()
      } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        treeLogger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "HTTP request failed", e);
        return;
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        treeLogger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "Bad URL", e);
        return;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        treeLogger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "I/O error on HTTP request", e);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean setupMode(TreeLogger logger, boolean developmentMode) {
    this.developmentMode = developmentMode;
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected HtmlUnitThread createHtmlUnitThread(BrowserVersion browser,
      String url) {
    return new Utf8HtmlUnitThread(browser, url, shell.getTopLogger()
        .branch(TreeLogger.SPAM, "logging for HtmlUnit thread"),
        developmentMode);
  }
}
```

It is mostly a bunch of copy/paste from original code. The important stuff is here (lines 103 to 105):

```
WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(new URL(url));
webRequest.setCharset("utf-8");
Page page = webClient.getPage(webRequest);
```

This run style must be activated by configuring the gwt arguments. In my case, I added this on the command line:

```
-Dgwt.args="-runStyle Utf8HtmlUnit"
```

IMHO, GWT should provide a way to configure the `WebClient` and the `WebRequest`, or at least support a `charset` attribute to the `script` tag in xml module files.

I filed a bug to the GWT team about this : [Issue 8171](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8171).

Comment: Does your HTML host page explicitly says it's UTF-8? (`<meta charset=utf-8>` or similar?)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I don't see what it has to do with the host page charset. What if I have 2 external scripts in 2 different charset?

Comment: Sorry, useless comment: the host page obviously is the one from GWT's JUnit. Re. the "2 external scripts in 2 different charsets", how your proposed change would work here? Isn't it just forcing UTF-8 for the host page?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Well, my solution is just a workaround, it's obviously not perfect. The `charset` attribute to the `script` tag is probably the best solution for this specific problem. And I think it would also be nice to have a way to configure `WebClient` and `WebRequest` in the test case, not only to set a different charset but maybe to add various headers and other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `Accept-Charset` of the WebClient's HTTP requests to `utf-8` by means of the 
[addRequestHeader(String, String)](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#addRequestHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this as soon as I manage to override/configure the WebClient instanciated by GWTTestCase. Any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what GWTTestCase is. If you do have the WebClient instance, then that's all. You could also try to generate a WebRequest manually, however, I can't confirm all subsequent request generated by the original WebRequest will copy the same headers as the original one... that's why I recommended setting it directly to the WebClient.